# ReactJS: How to kill `serve -s build`

Tags: reactjs, npm, serve

[Serve is a library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve) that allows you to serve your React build folder similar to `npm start`

Create an app with `npx create-react-app .`

Then run the following the following to create build and [serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve) the app

```
npm run build
npm install -g serve
serve -s build
```

[image]

It works perfectly, only how does one kill the listening on port 5000
`control c` brings back the suspended terminal prompt and `lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -n -P` indicates that it is no longer listening on port 5000.
pkill -9 node does not do it.

Even though it appears not to be listening on port 5000 I can go to localhost:5000 and it serves up the file as though it were listening on 5000;

NOTE:  this happened on MacOS

Comment: After you kill it, you say that you can still go to localhot:5000 and see it. However, try this: close all incognito windows, kill the process, and then open a new incognito window and try going to localhost:5000. What do you see?

Comment: Incognito shows the appropriate response.  (serves files on 5000 only when serve is running).  Yet `Empty cach Hard Reload` does not show the appropriate response.

Comment: If `Empty Cache and Hard Reload` doesn't work properly then the issue is probably with the content you're serving. Your screenshot hints to me that you're using `workbox`, and a service worker will definitely continue serving content once the server is offline.

Comment: `sudo pkill node` and then try.

Comment: Yes I am employing `service worker` perhaps the appropriate question is how do you kill a `service worker`?  It gets really weird because I am getting `console.log` from two different programs employing their own `service workers` on 5000.

Comment: @Samim Hakimi that did not work

Comment: @Nelles "Killing a service worker" is a separate question, but I think you should do some more research on what service workers *are* and how they work. As a side note, in the Chrome inspector, you can see service workers under Application > Service Workers.

Comment: @forresthopkinsa Ok thanks - yes I am working service worker demo right now while I learn it and this is what occurred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're still seeing content even after the server is killed is because you're using a Service Worker. Service Workers will cache content so that even when a user is offline, they can continue to use your web app. What you're experiencing is the intended functionality.

You can make your life a little easier by using Incognito Mode when working with service workers, so you can easily reset your browser and thereby clear any active service workers.

I'd recommend you read more of the Workbox [documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox) as I can see you're working with that framework.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to stop a service worker is through the Chrome Dev tools panel.
[image]